# Extending a CSS stylesheet?

Tags: css, inheritance, stylesheet, multiple-domains

An interesting problem but maybe it has already been solved. I have a collection of CSS style sheets that apply to multiple domains. The way it has been architected, both domains share the same CSS files and add their own definitions and rules to the stylesheets. Our system is as such that anytime a developer makes a change to a CSS file that belongs to a particular domain, then that very same change needs to be done in another domain's style sheet as well.

For instance if I have two domains: Main, SubMain. BOth of these share a stylesheet called global.css and a developer working on the SubMain domain changes this stylesheet by adding a new rule. To ensure that things do not break in the Main domain, the developer needs to go ahead and add the same rule to global.css to the main domain's global.css stylesheet.

Why this does not have the same shared location is beyond me since this is a shared engineering project. My understanding is that the reason being that the changes were to be applied immediately and unfortunately the only option was to use the same stylesheet + directory structure across all the domains.
But this problem does exist and it is tremendous overhead. Is there anyway to extend CSS stylesheets such that domain specific CSS can be added to the extended stylesheets.

If not, what other solutions can be proposed ?

Comment: You can include stylesheets across domains

Comment: What do you mean? That is exactly what we are doing.

Comment: Then why do you need to update two stylesheets?

Comment: If I have global.css then it exists in both the domains and each domain basically modifies certain rules and adds new rules of its own.  Changes in any one domain added need to be seen in another domain as well since they can be common. I would rather add the common changes to the main stylesheet which can then be inherited by the child stylesheets. If that makes any sense (obviously my assumption on CSS inheritance is theoretical and OOP inspired)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same code in two places, why have two files (and this goes for coding as well - methods or variables or whatever)? If you use something more than, keep it in one place and reference to it everywhere else.

What you need to do is to have the `Main` website point at a local copy of the `CSS` file (like so):

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/global.css">
```

... and then on the `SubMain` website, include in your headers a link to the `Main` website's CSS file (like so):

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="http://mainwebsite.com/css/global.css">
```

To solve your problem, only have the editable CSS file/files on one domain (the `Main` one), and then link to them using absolute URLs in the other (`SubMain`) website.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand you. I dont know where your problem is. Do you want to add 2 css style sheets?

```
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or do you want that 2 domains using 1 style sheet?

```
    <link href="http://url.com/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Both of the domains can use this. You are not linking in the directory of the style sheet. You put the link of your style in it. This will solve your problem.

Comment: If I have global.css then it exists in both the domains and each domain basically modifies certain rules and adds new rules of its own. Changes in any one domain added need to be seen in another domain as well since they can be common. I would rather add the common changes to the main stylesheet which can then be inherited by the child stylesheets. If that makes any sense (obviously my assumption on CSS inheritance is theoretical and OOP inspired)

Comment: I wrote down an explanation in the comment. i believe that explains the problem I am facing. Can you tell me what you did not understand ?

Answer (score 0):

Both domains can use one CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://myotherdomain.com/css/global.css">
```

Just link to one CSS file.

Or if you really want to "sync" them you could create a rsync script but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes. But global.css in domain 1 and global.css in domain 2 are different files. They both root from the same file but they add modifications. Hence linking them would not make any sense because some rules that are unique to domain 1 should not be in domain 2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It's apparent that you know you can include stylesheets across domains:

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="http://example.com/global.css">
```

But did you know that you can include multiple stylesheets?  Create a single stylesheet that has all of the "master" styles and put it in global.css on *one* of the domains (your choice).  The styles unique to each domain can be in a stylesheet specific to that domain.

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="http://example.com/css/global.css">
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/css/specific.css">
```